# How to investigate why the event grid delivery failed?

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to use event grid. On the screen below on the event grid subscription details chart I can see that there is a delivery failed event. However, I don't know how I can check the reasons of failure. The subscriber is an azure function, and in the logs I see it wasn't invoked.

[image]

How to debug the reasons why the delivery failed in the event grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry):

> Event Grid sends an event to the dead-letter location when it has tried all of its retry attempts. If Event Grid receives a 400 (Bad Request) or 413 (Request Entity Too Large) response code, it immediately schedules the event for dead-lettering. These response codes indicate delivery of the event will never succeed.

If the Function is never invoked, I'd suggest checking configuration as EventGrid would retry and you'd see that.

Comment: thank you for pointing, works, also have added diagnostic settings to populate logs. In my case the issue was pointing the wrong function app, but right function name. For some reasons there were two function apps with similar names and with same functions.